# Error while executing the script using chrome driver in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing an error while executing a script using the chrome driver in selenium. Here is the output:

Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067) on port 40787
Only local connections are allowed.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:03.216Z'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-NMVJBLGS', ip: '192.168.1.4', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '10.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at automationFramework.FirstTestCase.main(FirstTestCase.java:20)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:139)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:345)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:217)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:212)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:105)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    ... 7 more
```

This seems to be the root cause:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

It looks like the peer closes the socket connection premature. Can anyone think of the reason for that behaviour?